# Replace span values by a picture depending on a variable content

Tags: javascript, html, loops

In my webpage i have several spans and need to have them replaced by a picture depending on an associated variable value :

```js
for(i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++)  
document.getElementById('state_'+i).innerHTML = '<img src="picture_' + "~varstate("+i+")~" + '.png"></img>';
```

```html
<span id ="state_1">?</span>
<span id ="state_2">?</span>
<span id ="state_3">?</span>
<span id ="state_4">?</span>
<span id ="state_5">?</span>
```

varstate(1) ; varstate(2) ; varastate(3) ;  varastate(4) ; varastate(5)
are variables, they will only get 0 or 1 value.

Then, i need each span contents replaced by a that would be : picture_0.png or picture_1.png depending on varstate value.

The loop won't work , would you please tell me why ?

Comment: i don't really understand your question, your loop is woking

Comment: Are you sure about the quotation? I guess you mean something like `'<img src="picture_' + varstate(i) + '.png"></img>'`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
<span id="state_1">?</span>
<span id="state_2">?</span>
<span id="state_3">?</span>
<span id="state_4">?</span>
<span id="state_5">?</span>

<script>
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++)
        document.getElementById('state_' + i).innerHTML = '<img src="picture_' + varstate(i) + '.png" />';
</script>
```

Comment: No, it won't work either. I tried to go with a variable but still no chance !`<script type="text/javascript">
for(i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++) 

var variable = '~varstate("+i+")~'; 
document.getElementById('state_'+i).innerHTML = '<img src="picture_' + variable + '.png"></img>';
</script>`

Comment: The img tag is self-closed: <img ... />